# How to read image file and video file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to create a "Browse" button that allows the user to select either an image or video file, but the logic to read in those datatypes is different.

**Browse and read video file**

```
FileName = uigetfile('*.avi','Select the avi file');
v = VideoReader(FileName);
video = readFrame(v);
imshow(video, 'Parent', handles.axes1);
```

**Browse and read image file**

```
[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the jpg file');
Image = imread([PathName FileName]);
imshow(Image, 'Parent', handles.axes1);
```

How do I combine this logic into one function so that I can successfully load either an image or video with one load dialog?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Use `fileparts` to get the extension, then distinguish between both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could allow the user to select any file and then you use the extension to determine what to do.

```
[fname, pname] = uigetfile('*.*', 'Select an Image or Video File');
filename = fullfile(pname, fname);

[~, ~, extension] = fileparts(filename);

switch lower(extension)
    case {'.jpg', '.png', '.tif'}
        img = imread(filename);
    case {'.avi', '.mpg'}
        reader = VideoReader(filename);
        img = readFrame(reader);
    otherwise
        error('Invalid file selected');
end

imshow(img, 'Parent', handles.axes1);
```

Or you could provide multiple filters to `uigetfile`

```
filters = {'*.jpg', '*.avi'};

[fname, pname, findex] = uigetfile(filters, 'Select a Video or Image');

filename = fullfile(pname, fname);

if findex == 1 % jpeg
    img = imread(filename);
elseif findex == 2 % avi
    reader = VideoReader(filename);
    img = reader.readFrame();
end

imshow(img, 'parent', handles.axes1);
```